# AWS Elastic Beanstalk: nginx reload failed

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have provided to my Elastic Beanstalk environment nginx configuration according to [this article](https://medium.com/@marilu597/getting-to-know-and-love-aws-elastic-beanstalk-configuration-files-ebextensions-9a4502a26e3c). My application sits in a Docker container. The problem is that the environment fails to reload nginx.

Here's my config file:

```
files:
  "/etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf" :
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      client_max_body_size 500M;

container_commands:
  01_reload_nginx:
    command: "sudo service nginx reload"
```

And that results in failure (after `/var/log/eb-activity.log`):

```
EmbeddedPostBuild/postbuild_0_audio_explorer] : Starting activity...
[2019-03-04T21:45:01.064Z] INFO  [3274]  - [Application deployment app-8a62-190304_223307@1/StartupStage0/EbExtensionPostBuild/Infra-EmbeddedPostBuild/postbuild_0_audio_explorer/Command 01_reload_nginx] : Starting activity...
[2019-03-04T21:45:01.100Z] INFO  [3274]  - [Application deployment app-8a62-190304_223307@1/StartupStage0/EbExtensionPostBuild/Infra-EmbeddedPostBuild/postbuild_0_audio_explorer/Command 01_reload_nginx] : Activity execution failed, because:  (ElasticBeanstalk::ExternalInvocationError)


[2019-03-04T21:45:01.100Z] INFO  [3274]  - [Application deployment app-8a62-190304_223307@1/StartupStage0/EbExtensionPostBuild/Infra-EmbeddedPostBuild/postbuild_0_audio_explorer/Command 01_reload_nginx] : Activity failed.
[2019-03-04T21:45:01.100Z] INFO  [3274]  - [Application deployment app-8a62-190304_223307@1/StartupStage0/EbExtensionPostBuild/Infra-EmbeddedPostBuild/postbuild_0_audio_explorer] : Activity failed.
[2019-03-04T21:45:01.100Z] INFO  [3274]  - [Application deployment app-8a62-190304_223307@1/StartupStage0/EbExtensionPostBuild/Infra-EmbeddedPostBuild] : Activity failed.
[2019-03-04T21:45:01.122Z] INFO  [3274]  - [Application deployment app-8a62-190304_223307@1/StartupStage0/EbExtensionPostBuild] : Activity failed.
[2019-03-04T21:45:01.122Z] INFO  [3274]  - [Application deployment app-8a62-190304_223307@1/StartupStage0] : Activity failed.
[2019-03-04T21:45:01.122Z] INFO  [3274]  - [Application deployment app-8a62-190304_223307@1] : Completed activity. Result:
  Application deployment - Command CMD-Startup failed
```

When I remove section:

```
container_commands:
  01_reload_nginx:
    command: "sudo service nginx reload"
```

Deployment goes smooth.

Any ideas? How can I get information on what precisely goes wrong with the command? If I ssh to my instance, I can execute command without a problem.

Comment: but you need to provide whole config, not only one line

Comment: I don't think `sudo service nginx reload` is necessary. Just remove it permanently. Not sure why it fails though

Comment: @NeverBe That's the whole config. I don't have anything else yet, I'd like to figure out first ho to troubleshoot this one.

Comment: @brocknz After I update e.g. `client_max_body_size` I am pretty sure nginx reload is mandatory if I want new config to be loaded. it could be though that upon environment creation it's not needed. If I add it after I create env and then deploy, again command fails. I'd like to see why command fails. One other mention `01_reload_nginx` only points to pasted logs.

Comment: @LukaszTracewski yep, but doesn't the elastic beanstalk deployment process do the nginx reload for you? Have you tried changing `client_max_body_size` in a subsequent deployment and testing if the change was applied?

Comment: @brocknz You're right, it reloaded the script automagically. Oh well. I am still puzzled why the command did not work, even though it's not required. I will be happy to accept your answer - thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The elastic beanstalk deployment process will do the nginx reload for you, so you can remove it from your script permanently and avoid the error. Figuring out why exactly the command failed will just be academic

Comment: The problem I have is that while I'm polling the folder /etc/ngingx/conf.d I see the files from my .ebextensions appearing... but then something completely deletes nginx and reinstalls it so my files get deleted by the time the app has started. Any ideas?